# java.io.FileNotFoundException localhost/../gateway.php

Tags: php, flash-builder

I am trying to connect to a Data/service for my application in Flash Builder 4.5 but get an `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error

This is what I did:

> Data -> Connect to PHP (runtime) -> click here to generate a sample ->
>   I filled in all the information and clicked on -> connect to Database.

After this I got:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: localhost:8888/../../bin-debug/gateway.php
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have created a folder into the main folder and inside that folder I have added the /bin-debug/gateway.php and also the globals.php amfphp and core folder... but I should be able to just point the flash builder to the current location instead of creating new folders. 

After I created new folders I got a new error: Server error

The class {Zend_Amf_Adobe_DbInspector} could not be found under the class path {/Zend_Amf_Adobe_DbInspector.php}

anyone?

Answer (score -1):

A while ago I had the same exact problem, the solution for me was to correct web root directory in my project properties. (I had wrong apache htdocs folder)
Hope this helps you too.